# Laravel form after repeated tries auto switches from POST call to GET call

Tags: laravel

I have the below code. It accepts a form input and routes it as a post. The input is searched for in a model and the results are returned.
The below code WORKS in every scenario except one.

A search term that satisfies the validation is entered. A second search is done with no entry. This returns the error.

Note: Empty search is fine as long at is is being done from 'LocalHost'. When done in 'LocalHost/search/' it throws an error.

EDIT: It tries to make a GET call even though form method is post.

ERROR

```
Users/$user/Desktop/store/store/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="/search/" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          {{csrf_field()}}
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Search</button>
</form>
```

Router

```
Route::post('/search', 'ProductController@search');
```

Controller Function

```
public function search(Request $request)
{

$request->validate([
  'search' => 'required|min:2'
]);

$term = $request->input('search');

$products = Product::search($term)->get();
return view('products.index', compact('products'));

}
```

Model Scope

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $term)
{
  return $query->where('name', $term);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably redirecting to `/search` and you don't have a corresponding GET route for that URL.

I would ditch the minimum length requirement, possibly check the length in the controller action and return something either way. Users expect feedback even if their input is lacking, but that's a UX discussion.

Let me know if removing `min:2` from the request does the trick.

Comment: I removed min:2. No change. Is bootstrap messing it up do you think?

Comment: I switched some things around and you are right it is trying to use a GET  call even though form is set to post

Answer (score 0):

I'd check to see how your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class is handling ValidationExceptions.  I agree with SLow Loris, something somewhere is bouncing the request to a GET action, and there might be a redirect in there.  It's also possible there's a server configuration error.  I've seen it happen where `http` requests that Apache redirects to `https` lost sight of the action and parameters in the process.  Seems less likely since your initial POST is working though, but it might be worth a look.

If you know what route is being attempted, you could test this by setting up a new dummy GET endpoint that just prints a debug statement.  If you don't know what route it is and need to find out, since `no message` isn't very descriptive, add something like this to that Handler class:

```
public function render ($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        dd($e->getHeaders())
    }
}
```

If the request headers don't reference the route being attempted, you could temporarily alter `api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php::getRouteForMethods()` and force it to print more details about the `$request` object just before the `methodNotAllowed` method would get called.  If I were to guess, `$request->path()` will point you in the right direction.

Comment: returns:  public static function fromAction(array $action, $subClass = null)
    {
        $parameters = is_string($action['uses'])
                        ? static::fromClassMethodString($action['uses'])
                        : (new ReflectionFunction($action['uses']))->getParameters();
 
        return is_null($subClass) ? $parameters : array_filter($parameters, function ($p) use ($subClass) {
            return $p->getClass() && $p->getClass()->isSubclassOf($subClass);
        });
    }

Comment: "Class App\Http\Controllers\Exception does not exist"
I added use App\Http\Controllers\Exception;